# Headers for connecting to a SOAP webservice using PHP

Tags: php, soap, header

I am trying to connect to a SOAP webservice using php. I am very new to using php.

I can connect to the service, the test below returns a list of all the available functions of the webservice.

```
$url = "http://...client_ip.../dkServiceDefault/dkWSItemsCGI.exe/wsdl/IItemService";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

If I try to access one of these functions(ex. NumberOfModifiedItems) then I get an error stating that I need to supply a SOAP header with a username and password.

According to the documentation of the SOAP service the header needs to look like this:

```
<soap:Header>
    <q1:BasicSecurity id="h_id1" xmlns:q1="urn:dkWSValueObjects">
        <Username xsi:type="xsd:string">username</Username>
        <Password xsi:type="xsd:string">password</Password>
    </q1:BasicSecurity>
</soap:Header>
```

How can I make this header in php? How do I attach it to the SoapClient? I have a username and password but I can't figure out how to create the exact header to send to the webservice. I have tried following several tutorials, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I highly recommend using a library instead of PHPs built in soap class. I usually use this one https://github.com/econea/nusoap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass SOAP headers with [SoapHeader](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php) class and [SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php) method:

```
<?php
$url = "http://...client_ip.../dkServiceDefault/dkWSItemsCGI.exe/wsdl/IItemService";
$client = new SoapClient($url);

$namespace = "urn:dkWSValueObjects";
$authentication = array(
    'Username' => 'yourname',
    'Password' => 'yourpassword'
);
$header = new SoapHeader($namespace, 'BasicSecurity', $authentication, false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
?>
```